# How can i redirect to a particular page when clicking Android device Back button using Ionic Framework

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the Ionic framework. How can I redirect to a particular page when clicking the Android device Back button? There should make a comparison of the current page, and depending upon this comparison our back page is determining. How it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `onBackPressed()` method of `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
  // code here to do whatever you want when back is pressed
}
```